# Returned array gets 'cannot find symbol' error

Tags: java, arrays, methods

I keep getting the `"cannot find symbol"` error. It says that it cannot find 'identifier' in both `identifier.toString` and `System.out.println(identifier)` Any thoughts as to why it can't find that string array that I returned?

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
//recive data from user, Display data, Store Date to file, retrieve data from file
public class Library
{
    public static String [] ident()
    {

        Scanner inputFile1 = new Scanner("Identifiers");
        Scanner inputFile2 = new Scanner("Titles");
        Scanner inputFile3 = new Scanner("Descriptions");


        String[] identifier = new String[405];
        for (int i = 0; i < 406; i++)
        {
            identifier[i] = inputFile1.nextLine();
        }

        String[] title = new String[405];
        for (int i = 0; i < 406; i++)
        {
            title[i] = inputFile2.nextLine();
        }

        String[] description = new String[405];
        for (int i = 0; i < 406; i++)
        {
            description[i] = inputFile3.nextLine();
        }
    return identifier;
    }

    public static void main(String args)
    {
        Library.ident();
        identifier.toString();
        System.out.println(identifier);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to store the return value in a variable

```
public static void main(String args)
{
    String[] identifier = Library.ident();
    identifier.toString();
    System.out.println(identifier);
}
```

Comment: That was super helpful, I appreciate it. 
I'm getting an exception now that looks something like this. (I'm an inexperienced programmer and don't know how to handle something like this)
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException: No line found
    at java.util.Scanner.nextLine(Scanner.java:1585)
    at Library.ident(Library.java:17)
    at Library.main(Library.java:37)

I'd really appreciate if you could point me in the right direction.

Comment: Look at the [scanner api doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html). If you are passing a string to Scanner which is not what you want as I see it. If you want to pass a file use the code like `new Scanner(new File("Identifiers"))`

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems in your code.

- First of all: The `ident` method returns a value (`identifier`) and you are not using this value inside your `main` method. Instead you are trying to access the variable `identifier` directly, but it is only visible/ accessible inside the `ident` method. A solution to this would be:

  `String[] identifier = Library.ident();
    identifier.toString();`
- Second issue: in my opinion the for-loops will cause some trouble. As you can see, the array is initalized with 405 elements. If you want to iterate over all of them, it is from 0 to 404 and not 406.

  `String[] identifier = new String[405];
    for (int i = 0; i < 406; i++)`

Answer (score 0):

The variable **identifier** is declared ONLY in the method `ident` therefore is not visible outside that scope...

and you can not access to it unless you assign the return of that method to some variable object...